# Meteor JS database workflow

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

As far as I understand, I "`publish`" named collection `server-side`, on the `client side` I "`subscribe`" to that collection and pass them to `Template`, where I work only with the data, provided by "published" collection.

Please comment, have I got it right, and what should I do if I have a big collection that I don't want to retreive at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. When using large collections you should add parameters to the publish and/or limit the amount of records being published.

Theres a good explanation about publish/subscribe on [Meteorpedia](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Understanding_Meteor_Publish_and_Subscribe)

Comment: Thanks, got it, but how can I flush the data in my Meteor.Collection? It seems to add data to client's collection.

Comment: The data is synchronized automatically.

Comment: I mean I publish "clients" with 1 record and publish "clients-find" that returns 1 record, so in the template where I am iterating that collection it adds up that found record, so I have 2 records. How can I get around this? Thanks.